# are there any additional inject shorthand

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I recently ran into this issue:
I've always used inject like so (i knew that (0) part is optional and can be omitted)

```
array = [13,23,13]
#=> [13, 23, 13]
array.inject(0) { |sum,i| sum+i }
#=> 49
```

By chance i found out that you can use:

```
array.inject(:+)
#=> 49
array.inject(:-)
#=> -23
array.inject(:*)
#=> 3887
array.inject(:/)
#=> 0
```

Googling on the issue i found a nice [article on inject](http://blog.jayfields.com/2008/03/ruby-inject.html), but no mentioning there about what i've tried....
Can anyone explain to me or give some info about these inject commands that I've just used?

Comment: Another form of shorthand is the [`sum`](http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/sum) method or [`reduce`](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_125/Enumerable/reduce).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the doc on [`Enumerable#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject):

> ... If you specify a symbol instead, then each element in the collection will be passed to the named method of memo. In either case, the result becomes the new value for memo. At the end of the iteration, the final value of memo is the return value for the method.
>
> If you do not explicitly specify an initial value for memo, then uses the first element of collection is used as the initial value of memo.

So, if you specify a symbol, it treats it as a method name and invokes this method on every element of the enumerable, replacing memo as stated above. Now, the math operators (+-*/) are just methods, nothing else. These lines produce identical result:

```
13 + 23 # => 36
13.+(23) # => 36
13.send(:+, 23) # => 36
```

When you pass a symbol to `inject` or `reduce` it uses the third form to dynamically apply that operator to elements:

```
[1,2,3].inject(:+) # => 6
```

This shorthand can be used with methods other than operators as well:

```
[{"a"=>1}, {"b"=>2}].inject(:merge) # => {"a"=>1, "b"=>2}
```

Comment: I edited your answer to reflect that the symbol syntax is not restricted to operators, but can be used with other methods as well, as this seems important to the original question.  Hope you don't mind the edit!