# Symbol vs. Proc in `Enumerable#inject`

Tags: ruby, symbols, inject, enumerable, proc

Given that `Enumerable#inject` can take either a symbol or a block as the method to be used in the iteration, as explained in an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526290), is there any reason to use the `&` in conjunction with `Symbol#to_proc` within `Enumerable#inject`? The following pairs return the same result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].inject(:+)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].inject(&:+)

[:a, :b, :c].inject({a: {b: {c: 1}}}, :fetch)
[:a, :b, :c].inject({a: {b: {c: 1}}}, &:fetch)
```

Is there any use case where using a symbol and using a block (created by `&`) have different results? Are there any cases where one can be used and not the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have to support old versions of Ruby (1.8.6 or older) and you're using a library that defines `Symbol#to_proc` for those versions (like active support), the version using `&` will work and the other will not.

Other than that the only differences between the two versions are that the version using a symbol is faster and that the version using `&` will be affected if you redefine `Symbol#to_proc` - though I can't think of a case where that'd be useful. So no, if you don't need to support Ruby 1.8.6, there's no reason to not use the symbol form.