# How do I pass (2-∞) arguments to a ruby method?

Tags: ruby, arguments

I'm working on a very simple exercise: a method that can multiply between two and an indefinite number of floats. My first idea for doing this was to use the splat operator:

```
def multiply a, b, *rest
  a * b * rest
end
```

That was unsuccessful. I then tried this:

```
def multiply *numbers
  total = 1
  numbers.each do |x|
   total = total * x 
  end
  total
end
```

The above is *almost* successful—the problem is that it will accept a single argument, and I want it to require at least two. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many options. The one the author of the exercise probably intended for you to use is `inject`:

```
def multiply(*numbers)
  numbers.inject(&:*)
end
```

This will cause the same problem as your second implementation of `multiply` in that it will accept 0 or 1 arguments. You can fix this by simply raising an `ArgumentError` if you don't have at least two:

```
def multiply(*numbers)
  raise ArgumentError unless numbers.length >= 2
  numbers.inject(&:*)
end
```

You can go the other way and accept two actual arguments and splat the rest, and simply build the complete array you intend to multiply together:

```
def multiply(a, b, *rest)
  [a, b, *rest].inject(&:*)
end
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that you can also pass a string as the second argument to `raise`, which can serve as a helpful message.

Comment: Super, thank you. I didn't know about `inject`. Can you explain the `(&:*)` notation that follows the method?

Comment: @adc See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961030/ruby-ampersand-colon-shortcut

Comment: @adc the shorthand works a little differently for inject/reduce than for each/map/etc., see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526290/are-there-any-additional-inject-shorthand as well

Comment: You could also use `a * b * rest.inject(1, &:*)`, to avoid unpacking and packing `rest`.